# Generate JWT custom token

Tags: spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-authorization-server

I want to implement Spring Authorization Server using the following code:

```
    import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.JWKSet;
    import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.RSAKey;
    import com.nimbusds.jose.jwk.source.JWKSource;
    import com.nimbusds.jose.proc.SecurityContext;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
    import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
    import org.springframework.core.Ordered;
    import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;
    import org.springframework.security.config.Customizer;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
    import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.AuthorizationGrantType;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.ClientAuthenticationMethod;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.OidcScopes;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClient;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.client.RegisteredClientRepository;
    import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.authorization.config.ProviderSettings;
    import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
    
    import java.security.KeyPair;
    import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
    import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
    import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
    import java.util.UUID;
    
    @Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)
    public class AuthorizationServerConfig {
    
        @Bean
        @Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
        public SecurityFilterChain authServerSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfiguration.applyDefaultSecurity(http);
            return http.formLogin(Customizer.withDefaults()).build();
        }
    
        @Bean
        public RegisteredClientRepository registeredClientRepository() {
            RegisteredClient registeredClient = RegisteredClient.withId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .clientId("articles-client")
                    .clientSecret("{noop}secret")
                    .clientAuthenticationMethod(ClientAuthenticationMethod.CLIENT_SECRET_BASIC)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.AUTHORIZATION_CODE)
                    .authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                    .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/login/oauth2/code/articles-client-oidc")
                    .redirectUri("http://127.0.0.1:8080/authorized")
                    .scope(OidcScopes.OPENID)
                    .scope("articles.read")
                    .build();
    
            return new InMemoryRegisteredClientRepository(registeredClient);
        }
    
        @Bean
        public JWKSource<SecurityContext> jwkSource() {
            RSAKey rsaKey = generateRsa();
            JWKSet jwkSet = new JWKSet(rsaKey);
            return (jwkSelector, securityContext) -> jwkSelector.select(jwkSet);
        }
    
        private static RSAKey generateRsa() {
            KeyPair keyPair = generateRsaKey();
            RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) keyPair.getPublic();
            RSAPrivateKey privateKey = (RSAPrivateKey) keyPair.getPrivate();
            return new RSAKey.Builder(publicKey)
                    .privateKey(privateKey)
                    .keyID(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
                    .build();
        }
    
        private static KeyPair generateRsaKey() {
            KeyPair keyPair;
            try {
                KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
                keyPairGenerator.initialize(2048);
                keyPair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(ex);
            }
            return keyPair;
        }
    
        @Bean
        public ProviderSettings providerSettings() {
            return ProviderSettings.builder()
                    .issuer("http://auth-server:9000")
                    .build();
        }
    }

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.provisioning.InMemoryUserDetailsManager;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;

import static org.springframework.security.config.Customizer.withDefaults;

@EnableWebSecurity
public class DefaultSecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests(authorizeRequests ->
                        authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
                )
                .formLogin(withDefaults());
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    UserDetailsService users() {
        UserDetails user = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
                .username("admin")
                .password("password")
                .roles("USER")
                .build();
        return new InMemoryUserDetailsManager(user);
    }

}
```

How I can extend this code and generate custom JWT token with some custom values?

Answer (score 2):

You should add custom jwtCustomizer into your AuthorizationServerConfig.class.

```
@Bean
        OAuth2TokenCustomizer<JwtEncodingContext> jwtCustomizer() {
            return context -> {
                if (context.getTokenType().getValue().equals(OidcParameterNames.ID_TOKEN)) {
                    Authentication principal = context.getPrincipal();
                    Set<String> authorities = principal.getAuthorities().stream()
                            .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
                    context.getClaims().claim(AUTHORITIES_CLAIM, authorities);
                }
            };
```